# awk's substr replacement

Tags: text-processing, awk, text-formatting

I downloaded a tab-separated file from [here](https://ftp.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/genomes/all/annotation_releases/4096/100/GCF_000393655.1_Nsyl/GCF_000393655.1_Nsyl_genomic.gff.gz):

```
##gff-version 3
#!gff-spec-version 1.21
#!processor NCBI annotwriter
#!genome-build Nsyl
#!genome-build-accession NCBI_Assembly:GCF_000393655.1
#!annotation-source NCBI Nicotiana sylvestris Annotation Release 100
##sequence-region NW_009338801.1 1 504
##species https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/Taxonomy/Browser/wwwtax.cgi?id=4096
NW_009338801.1  RefSeq  region  1       504     .       +       .       ID=NW_009338801.1:1..504;Dbxref=taxon:4096;Name=Unknown;bio-material=USDA:TW 136;chrom
osome=Unknown;gbkey=Src;genome=genomic;mol_type=genomic DNA;tissue-type=leaf
##sequence-region NW_009338802.1 1 9484
##species https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/Taxonomy/Browser/wwwtax.cgi?id=4096
NW_009338802.1  RefSeq  region  1       9484    .       +       .       ID=NW_009338802.1:1..9484;Dbxref=taxon:4096;Name=Unknown;bio-material=USDA:TW 136;chro
mosome=Unknown;gbkey=Src;genome=genomic;mol_type=genomic DNA;tissue-type=leaf
##sequence-region NW_009338803.1 1 7523
##species https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/Taxonomy/Browser/wwwtax.cgi?id=4096
NW_009338803.1  RefSeq  region  1       7523    .       +       .       ID=NW_009338803.1:1..7523;Dbxref=taxon:4096;Name=Unknown;bio-material=USDA:TW 136;chro
mosome=Unknown;gbkey=Src;genome=genomic;mol_type=genomic DNA;tissue-type=leaf
##sequence-region NW_009338804.1 1 46372
##species https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/Taxonomy/Browser/wwwtax.cgi?id=4096
NW_009338804.1  RefSeq  region  1       46372   .       +       .       ID=NW_009338804.1:1..46372;Dbxref=taxon:4096;Name=Unknown;bio-material=USDA:TW 136;chr
omosome=Unknown;gbkey=Src;genome=genomic;mol_type=genomic DNA;tissue-type=leaf
NW_009338804.1  Gnomon  pseudogene      32822   34172   .       -       .       ID=gene-LOC104209938;Dbxref=GeneID:104209938;Name=LOC104209938;gbkey=Gene;gene
=LOC104209938;gene_biotype=pseudogene;pseudo=true
NW_009338804.1  Gnomon  exon    32822   34172   .       -       .       ID=id-LOC104209938-1;Parent=gene-LOC104209938;Dbxref=GeneID:104209938;exon_number=1;gb
key=exon;gene=LOC104209938;model_evidence=Supporting evidence includes similarity to: 2 Proteins;number=1
##sequence-region NW_009338805.1 1 53328
##species https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/Taxonomy/Browser/wwwtax.cgi?id=4096
NW_009338805.1  RefSeq  region  1       53328   .       +       .       ID=NW_009338805.1:1..53328;Dbxref=taxon:4096;Name=Unknown;bio-material=USDA:TW 136;chr
omosome=Unknown;gbkey=Src;genome=genomic;mol_type=genomic DNA;tissue-type=leaf
NW_009338805.1  Gnomon  gene    10570   12535   .       -       .       ID=gene-LOC104217587;Dbxref=GeneID:104217587;Name=LOC104217587;gbkey=Gene;gene=LOC1042
17587;gene_biotype=protein_coding
NW_009338805.1  Gnomon  mRNA    10570   12535   .       -       .       ID=rna-XM_009770987.1;Parent=gene-LOC104217587;Dbxref=GeneID:104217587,Genbank:XM_0097
70987.1;Name=XM_009770987.1;gbkey=mRNA;gene=LOC104217587;model_evidence=Supporting evidence includes similarity to: 100%25 coverage of the annotated genomic f
eature by RNAseq alignments%2C including 2 samples with support for all annotated introns;product=ribosome-interacting GTPase 1-like;transcript_id=XM_00977098
7.1
NW_009338805.1  Gnomon  exon    12140   12535   .       -       .       ID=exon-XM_009770987.1-1;Parent=rna-XM_009770987.1;Dbxref=GeneID:104217587,Genbank:XM_
009770987.1;gbkey=mRNA;gene=LOC104217587;product=ribosome-interacting GTPase 1-like;transcript_id=XM_009770987.1
NW_009338805.1  Gnomon  exon    11826   11939   .       -       .       ID=exon-XM_009770987.1-2;Parent=rna-XM_009770987.1;Dbxref=GeneID:104217587,Genbank:XM_009770987.1;gbkey=mRNA;gene=LOC104217587;product=ribosome-interacting GTPase 1-like;transcript_id=XM_009770987.1
NW_009338805.1  Gnomon  exon    11521   11695   .       -       .       ID=exon-XM_009770987.1-3;Parent=rna-XM_009770987.1;Dbxref=GeneID:104217587,Genbank:XM_009770987.1;gbkey=mRNA;gene=LOC104217587;product=ribosome-interacting GTPase 1-like;transcript_id=XM_009770987.1
NW_009338805.1  Gnomon  exon    10570   10889   .       -       .       ID=exon-XM_009770987.1-4;Parent=rna-XM_009770987.1;Dbxref=GeneID:104217587,Genbank:XM_009770987.1;gbkey=mRNA;gene=LOC104217587;product=ribosome-interacting GTPase 1-like;transcript_id=XM_009770987.1
NW_009338805.1  Gnomon  CDS     12140   12154   .       -       0       ID=cds-XP_009769289.1;Parent=rna-XM_009770987.1;Dbxref=GeneID:104217587,Genbank:XP_009769289.1;Name=XP_009769289.1;gbkey=CDS;gene=LOC104217587;product=ribosome-interacting GTPase 1-like;protein_id=XP_009769289.1
NW_009338805.1  Gnomon  CDS     11826   11939   .       -       0       ID=cds-XP_009769289.1;Parent=rna-XM_009770987.1;Dbxref=GeneID:104217587,Genbank:XP_009769289.1;Name=XP_009769289.1;gbkey=CDS;gene=LOC104217587;product=ribosome-interacting GTPase 1-like;protein_id=XP_009769289.1
NW_009338805.1  Gnomon  CDS     11521   11695   .       -       0       ID=cds-XP_009769289.1;Parent=rna-XM_009770987.1;Dbxref=GeneID:104217587,Genbank:XP_009769289.1;Name=XP_009769289.1;gbkey=CDS;gene=LOC104217587;product=ribosome-interacting GTPase 1-like;protein_id=XP_009769289.1
NW_009338805.1  Gnomon  CDS     10813   10889   .       -       2       ID=cds-XP_009769289.1;Parent=rna-XM_009770987.1;Dbxref=GeneID:104217587,Genbank:XP_009769289.1;Name=XP_009769289.1;gbkey=CDS;gene=LOC104217587;product=ribosome-interacting GTPase 1-like;protein_id=XP_009769289.1
...
```

The following command failed to create multiple files for different column names e.g. NW_009592716.1.lst, NC_007500.1.lst, ....

```
cat GCF_000393655.1_Nsyl_genomic.gff |awk '$3=="CDS"' |
    sed 's/;/\t/g' |
    awk '{print $1,$7,$12}' |
    sed 's/Name=//g' |
    awk 'substr($3,11,11)==1 {print $3$2,$1}'  |
    sort |
    uniq |
    awk '{print >> $2 ".lst"; close($2)}'
```

it only creates one file instead of multiple files:

```
$ head NC_007500.1.lst
YP_358649.1- NC_007500.1
YP_358650.1+ NC_007500.1
YP_358650.1- NC_007500.1
YP_358651.1- NC_007500.1
YP_358652.1- NC_007500.1
YP_358653.1- NC_007500.1
YP_358654.1+ NC_007500.1
YP_358655.1+ NC_007500.1
YP_358656.1+ NC_007500.1
YP_358657.1- NC_007500.1
...
```

How is it possible to make the above command tolerant to different string length?

Thank you in advance,

Comment: What does your input data look like?

Comment: I bet all this could be done in a **single** awk program, just edit your question with input data and expected filename.

Comment: It is going to run like a dog if you append/close the output file for every line. Awk will write to at least 1000 output files concurrently, and close them automatically at end. In fact, your close() is invalid anyway: the filename is different to the one in the print.

Comment: You never need sed when you're using awk and you definitely don't need a pipleine of multiple calls to sed + awk and a UUOC to do anything. For example `cat GCF_000393655.1_Nsyl_genomic.gff | awk '$3=="CDS"' | sed 's/;/\t/g' | awk '{print $1,$7,$12}' | sed 's/Name=//g'` can be written as just `awk '$3=="CDS"{gsub(/;/,"\t"); $0=$1 OFS $7 OFS $12; gsub(/Name/,""); print}' GCF_000393655.1_Nsyl_genomic.gff`. If you [edit] your question to include concise, testable sample input and expected output then we can help you do whatever it is you're trying to do.

Comment: I updated the question and included the link to the input file and examples for filenames.

Comment: @EdMorton: The following command did not create any files ```cat GCF_000393655.1_Nsyl_genomic.gff | awk '$3=="CDS"{gsub(/;/,"\t"); $0=$1 OFS $7 OFS $12; gsub(/Name/,""); print}' |
    awk 'substr($3,11,11)==1 {print $3$2,$1}'  |
    sort |
    uniq |
    awk '{print >> $2 ".lst"; close($2)}' ```

Comment: It would be better if you set out clearly which of the key/value pairs you actually intend to extract rather than leaving it to people to interpret from your code.

Comment: @bu5hman I am sorry and I understand the problem. For [this file](https://cloudstor.aarnet.edu.au/plus/s/UY9EE4QnOaOQYEg). I would need the first column and the Parent value. Which get reversed in the output files

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, it should be possible to implement your entire chain of AWK and sed invocations as a single AWK program.

To answer your stated question, to check whether the last character of the third field is “1”, you can use

```
$3 ~ /1$/
```

instead of `substr`, so in your case

```
$3 ~ /1$/ {print $3$2,$1}
```

Answer (score 0):

I come up with

```
$3 == "CDS" && $1 ~ /1$/ {
        split($9,A,";") ;
        B=substr(A[4],6) ;
        V[B $7] = $1 ;
}
END {
        for (u in V) {
                print u  >> V[u] ;
                close(V[u]) ;
        }
}
```

resulting in 17042 files.

- `$3 == "CDS" && $1 ~ /1$/`  for `awk '$3=="CDS"'` and  `awk 'substr($3,11,11)==1`
- `split($9,A,";") ;` for  `sed 's/;/\t/g'` and  `awk '{print $1,$7,$12}'`
- `B=substr(A[4],6) ;` for `sed 's/Name=//g'`
- `V[B $7] = $1 ;` for `sort` and `uniq`

---

To execute the script, insert code in `filter.awk`, then

```
awk -f filter.awk file_to_parse
```

Comment: Thank you, how do I execute your script?

Comment: Thank you it works, but how would it be possible to each file an extension `.lst`?

Answer (score 0):

Using `gawk` and a variable `tgt` to define the name of the field you want to select out....

```
awk -F"[\t;:,=]" -v tgt="Genbank" '$3=="CDS"{
   for (f=4; f<=NF; f++) if ($f ~ tgt) {
     if ( $(f+1) ~ /\.1$/ ) out[$(f+1)$7" "$1]=$1".lst"}}
   END{PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@ind_num_asc"; 
      for (o in out) print o > out[o]}' GCF_000393655.1_Nsyl_genomic.gff

tail *.lst 

==> NW_009592652.1.lst <==
XP_009779696.1- NW_009592652.1

==> NW_009592685.1.lst <==
XP_009779697.1+ NW_009592685.1
XP_009779699.1- NW_009592685.1

==> NW_009592688.1.lst <==
XP_009779700.1+ NW_009592688.1
XP_009779701.1+ NW_009592688.1
XP_009779702.1+ NW_009592688.1

==> NW_009592716.1.lst <==
XP_009779703.1+ NW_009592716.1
```

Repeat for `tgt="Parent"` and input from `test.gff3` as per comments

```
tail *.lst

==> NbV1Ch18.lst <==
NBlab18G26040.1+ NbV1Ch18
NBlab18G26050.1- NbV1Ch18
NBlab18G26060.1+ NbV1Ch18
NBlab18G26070.1+ NbV1Ch18
NBlab18G26080.1- NbV1Ch18
NBlab18G26090.1- NbV1Ch18
NBlab18G26100.1- NbV1Ch18
NBlab18G26110.1- NbV1Ch18
NBlab18G26120.1+ NbV1Ch18
NBlab18G26130.1+ NbV1Ch18

==> NbV1Ch19.lst <==
NBlab19G29030.1+ NbV1Ch19
NBlab19G29040.1- NbV1Ch19
NBlab19G29050.1- NbV1Ch19
NBlab19G29060.1- NbV1Ch19
NBlab19G29070.1+ NbV1Ch19
NBlab19G29080.1+ NbV1Ch19
NBlab19G29090.1- NbV1Ch19
NBlab19G29100.1- NbV1Ch19
NBlab19G29110.1- NbV1Ch19
NBlab19G29120.1- NbV1Ch19
```

**Walkthrough**

Select your desired field as `tgt` and initially select out records on `CDS`

```
awk -F"[\t;:,=]" -v tgt="Genbank" '$3=="CDS"{
```

Iterate over the fields until you find `tgt`

```
   for (f=4; f<=NF; f++) if ($f ~ tgt) {
```

Check to see if your target field value `$(f+1)` ends in `.1` and if it does then store your formatted output in the `out` array with a value of the filename you want it to go to

```
     if ( $(f+1) ~ /\.1$/ ) out[$(f+1)$7" "$1]=$1".lst"}}
```

When done then set up `awk` to iterate over your output array based upon a numeric ascending sort of the indices in the array

```
   END{PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@ind_num_asc";
```

Then just iterate over your array printing the indices you want `o` into the respective files `out[o]`

```
      for (o in out) print o > out[o]}' GCF_000393655.1_Nsyl_genomic.gff
```

Comment: Thank you, it works with the above file but when I tried this [file](https://cloudstor.aarnet.edu.au/plus/s/UY9EE4QnOaOQYEg) it did not create any files. Any ideas?

Comment: Yip. Your data structure differs. in the first file you were selecting from the key/value pair in GENBANK but this does not exist with CDS in the second file, which only has only ID and PARENT keys. I suggest you take a look at the original intent and if you intended to select out on PARENT (which look to be the same in the first gff file) then just change `$12` to `$9` in the first code sample.

Comment: Thank you, Your orginal code with `GCF_000393655.1_Nsyl_genomic.gff` produced the following output.

```
$ cat NW_00935579.1.lst
XP_009802589.1+ NW_00935579.1
```

The 2 new versions:
`awk -F"[\t;]" '$3=="CDS"&&$9~/1$/{
  split($12,arr,"="); out[arr[2]$7" "$1]=$1".lst"}
  END{PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@ind_num_asc"; 
  for (o in out) print o > out[o]}' t.gff3`

`awk -F"[\t;=]" '$3=="CDS"&&$12~/1$/{
    out[$16$7" "$1]=$1".lst"}
    END{PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@ind_num_asc"; 
    for (o in out) print o > out[o]}' t.gff3`

produced only:

```
$ cat NbV1Ch06.lst
+ NbV1Ch06
```

Comment: @user977828 The new versions wont work with the old file because they have *different data structures* If you post a clarification saying which of the key/value pairs it is that you want to extract from the files then a "one stop" fix may be possible, but until you do..... we are just guessing. Please clarify your original post.

Comment: I am sorry and I understand the problem. For [this file](https://cloudstor.aarnet.edu.au/plus/s/UY9EE4QnOaOQYEg). I would need the first column and the Parent value. Which get reversed in the output files.